# Will parse open source provide reset password link ? how can i create one if not and also connect it with mail gun?

Tags: ios, node.js, parse-platform, mailgun, forgot-password

Will parse open source provide the reset password link  ? or should i make it in open source parse.
I saw few blogs on sending mails through mail gun,but couldn't find one to make a reset password link,The password is hashed by parse in database,It would be helpful if anyone could provide help with it.I am not used to parse cloud nor that much with node js ,server .